# Using tooling preview 1 Visual Studio 2015 for ESlint

Tags: visual-studio-2015, eslint

I have installed tooling preview 1 (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481) because i want VS to check ESLint, now I use VS-Code and it would be great if VS15 could take that task insteed.

Like this:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/eslint-now-officially-integrated-with-visual-studio-2015/23798

After I install Í get "Web Code Analysis" under Tools and i can select the .eslintrc to add my own rules. I have tried that by copying my other file that "Gulp Watch" uses, but that dont work. I have tried to changing the default rules but nothing happens.

Can someone that have installed this and it working explain how to add your own rules and get it to work, Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure if you got this figured out, but there's a few options in VS that might impact this. I think in your case, "Ignore nested files" might be the culprit. It's under Options -> Web -> Code Analysis. That said, this will also prevent it from analyzing .min.js files.

Answer (score 0):

You precise you had the problem with Tooling Preview 1, but I have known a similar problem with version 2. The bug has been reported (cf. [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/727)). The solution proposed by [markvp](https://github.com/markvp) solved my issue. Here is his post :

> We experienced this issue too.
>
> While they try to fix it... try this work-around...
>
> Check the Web\External folder in your VS installation folder (often
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0) for a file named
>   eslint.cmd
>
> If it doesn't exist, open a command prompt in that folder and type npm
>   install eslint
>
> If this doesn't fix your issue (or you already had an eslint.cmd
>   file), add the full location of that direction to your PATH
>   environment variable. e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\Web\External.
>
> (See google for instructions as it depends on your windows OS
>   version).
>
> If neither of these fix the issue, try manually deleting the eslint
>   subfolder in the node_modules folder and the two eslint files in the
>   Web\External folder. Then re-attempt the install above using a command
>   prompt with elevated privileges (running as Administrator).

Then if you add a [`.eslintrc`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) file at the root of your project, you can override the eslint rules.

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "angular": false
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [ "error", "single" ]
    // add rules here
  }
}
```

Please note that if you extend `"eslint:recommanded"` a lot of rules are already set up by default. More information can be found in the [official documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/).